# Updating div with ajax/json within a modal dialog form fails at random

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, dialog, carousel

I'm trying to update a div control (#test) with getJSON in a form displayed inside a modal dialog. The dialog is shown everytime a user clicks a defined link. Here is the function called:

```
// Displays modal dialog with a form
function job_description(job_id) {
    $('<div id="server-form"></div>').load('/description_form').dialog(
        {
            position: { 
                my: 'top top',
                at: 'top top',
                offset: '0 100',
                of: $('body')
            },
            width: 650,
            modal:true,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Job description details',
            buttons: { 
                "close": {
                class: "btn btn-primary",
                text: "Close",
                click: 
                    function() {
                        $( this ).remove();
                    }
                }
            },
            close: function(event,ui) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
    });
    var response = $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/descriptions_list/'+job_id,
      cache: false,
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function(response){
               var obj = $.parseJSON(response); 
               //console.log(obj.description.title);
               $('#test').html(obj.description.title);
          },
      error: function(msg) {
                alert('error: '+msg);
      }
    });
}
```

I know the ajax call always works (I checked the console and I never get the alert), but the #test div does not get updated sometimes. It happens randomly. The load() method at the beginning calls a REST service which actually loads the form, and then ajax is used to pull some data from another url. The #test div is inside a bootstrap carousel also. Here is the div portion I'm trying to update:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="description-editor" class="carousel slide" style="padding-left: 20%;padding-right: 20%">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <form>
      <div class="item well" style="height: 500px">
        <h3>Title</h3><br/>
        <div id="test" style="width: 300px; height: 200px">I should get updated...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item well" style="height: 500px">
        <h3>Some other info</h3><br/>
        <p>To be completed</p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#description-editor" data-slide="prev" data-interval="">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#description-editor" data-slide="next" data-interval="">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the #test div does not ALWAYS get updated when the call is successful (which always is). I tried using async: false, but that didn't help either...I'm using the jquery 1.7.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you confirmed using chrome's console, or another sniffer, what is being returned? Perhaps invalid json is being returned in certain cases.

Comment: Additionally, perhaps you shouldn't trigger the second ajax call until the .load from the first on succeeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 issues with your code:

1. As pointed out by Chris, the way you call jQuery load assumes it loads instantly (synchronously), which it doesn't. You need to implement `.load()` as per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and only proceed with the `.dialog()` and `.ajax()`, once the load has finished. I.e. by putting/triggering all that code in the "complete" callback param of load. Note, although `.load()` does implicitly set the content of your div asynchronously, the subsequent ajax call can still happen before the div has loaded.
2. You should not need to parse the `.ajax()` response into JSON when specifying the datatype as JSON. The `.ajax()` [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) say:

> **success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)** - 
>   The function gets passed three
>   arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to
>   the dataType parameter...

and

> **dataType** - "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object

I'd also implement the other parameters of success so you can see whether there is anything funny coming through in them when you see your error.

Comment: As you and Chris suggested I moved my code inside a callback function inside load() and so far there are no errors coming up. Thanks guys!